# Google Maps and Rails - How to build locations data from Ruby model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use Google Maps API without the gmaps4rails gem.

It's a normal application where each instance of the model is a marker, and I'd like that each marker would have it's own info window.

In this part of the code lies the problem:

```
var locations = [];
<% @listings.each do |l| %>
  locations.push([<%=raw l.latitude%>, <%=raw l.longitude %>]);
<% end %>
```

The code works as is, but when I try to call a third object that is not a number (say `<%=raw l.title %>`) the maps simply does not load. Moreover, any text inside Ruby will not load - say `<%=raw "text" %>` or `<%= "text" %>` while `<%= 2 %>` does work.

How can I surpass this issue and call the ruby model to build an infowindow with? Is it JSON? If so, I would I use it?

Thanks in advance,
Tiago

Map partial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.3, 103.85),
          zoom: 12,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl:true
        };

        var locations = [];
        <% @listings.each do |l| %>
           locations.push([<%=raw l.latitude%>, <%=raw l.longitude %>]);
        <% end %>

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("index-map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();      

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
            map: map
          });


          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent("<div>"+locations[i][2]+"</div>");
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));

        };

      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
def index
    @q = Listing.search(params[:q])
    @listings = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
    var locations = [];
    <% @listings.each do |l| %>
       locations.push([<%=raw l.latitude%>, <%=raw l.longitude %>]);
    <% end %>
```

With:

```
    var locations = <%= raw @listings.to_json %>;
```

Comment: Works great. For others seeking same issue, element is referenced further as in: `position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]["latitude"], locations[i]["longitude"])`